# jQuery UI Sortable remove nested but not add it back

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

What i want to achieve is that the Test 2 with list-group-item static can't be changed but the nested must be changeable. In and out Test 1.

If i change , items: 'li' to , items: 'li:not(.static)' i can drag and drop Child 1 Test 2 outside Test 1 but can't move it to Test 1 as before.

How can i achieve this?

Test Sortable:

```
<ol class="afvalstromen list-group ui-sortable" id="list">
    <li class="list-group-item" id="sortable_114" data-order="1">
        <div class="ui-sortable-handle">
            Test 1
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item static" id="sortable_1" data-order="2">
        <div class="ui-sortable-handle">
            Test 2
        </div>
        <ol>
            <li class="list-group-item" id="sortable_19" data-order="3">
                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">
                    Child 1 Test 2
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" id="sortable_112" data-order="4"
                style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                <div class="ui-sortable-handle">
                    Child 2 Test 2
                </div>
                <ol>
                    <li class="list-group-item" id="sortable_113" data-order="5">
                        <div class="ui-sortable-handle">
                            Child 1 Child 2
                        </div>
                        <ol></ol>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $ol.nestedSortable({
        handle: 'div'
        , items: 'li'
        , toleranceElement: '> div'
        , update: function () {
            var order = JSON.stringify($(this).nestedSortable('toArray'))

            $.ajax({
                data: {'order': order},
                type: 'POST',
                ect etc
```

Comment: You want to drag child of `test 2` and drop it in `test 1`? I didn't understand your problem. Can you add fiddle?

Comment: @AliSoltani It worlks when i drag and drop "Child 1 Test 2" outside to the root, but reverse not. This only when i the config js is set to : " , items: 'li' " to  " , items: 'li:not(.static)' "

Comment: It would be always favorable on your part if you could create a working DEMO of your code so that some one can have a quick look at the issues in your code. So it would be great if you can do so here as well.